# In .htaccess, redirect all domains except one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have multiple domains on my server. I want to redirect all of them to one (example.net).

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I’m redirecting all URLs on my server to one main domain, but that domain is also redirecting to itself. So www.example.net returns `301 Moved Permanently` and redirects back to itself. I’m told that this isn’t good for SEO. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to add a *Rewritecond* to prevent it from redirecting when you’re already on the domain that you want. There are loads of examples online if you google it, or see the [RewriteCond section of Apache’s mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

What you’re looking for is something like:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just small note:
Thanks goes to TRiG, but I had to remove one slash to make it work correctly (coz it added two slashes after domain name). This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net$1 [R=301,L]
```