# How to use htaccess to always redirect to https://www.example.com with multiple domains?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, multiple-domains

I have the next code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

With this code the following URLs are redirecting everyone to `https://www.example.com`.

- `http://example.es`
- `http://www.example.es`
- `https://example.es`

But the next one is not redirected:

```
https://www.mydomain.es
```

Could some one help me with this problem?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059301/htaccess-redirect-all-domains-except-one

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition on 3-rd line from the bottom says: redirect only requests to hostname not starting with `www` or `subdomain`... so `https://www.mydomain.es` is not redirected - first rule not applied (HTTPS is on) and second rule not applied as hostname `www.mydomain.es` does start with `www`...

Not absolutely sure, but I guess you want the condition to be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mydomain.com [NC]
```

You can also consider to merge both rules (but I'm not sure if your question shows all your requirements):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=301]
```