# htaccess capture all domains + subdirectories except one and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to capture all domain names pointing to my server and redirect them to my main domain. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11059848/6672739) helped me part of the way in capturing all domains that aren't the main domain, but i would also like to capture all the sub directories and point them to the home page, for example:

a) `old.com` => `example.com`

b) `old.com/test` => `example.com`

c) `old.com/variable/1/2/3/4` => `example.com`

my current code only works for point a)

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*example\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+) [NC]`